# Is it possible to do modular build in Cruise Control?

Tags: cruisecontrol

I have a project with sub modules say (//MyProject/Module1 & //MyProject/Module2). 
I would like to build only specific module i.e if the user wants to build only Module2 & not Module1 inside MyProject. Is it possible in Cruise Control to do modular build?

If yes, what are the changes I have to do in config.xml?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, and this is a big limitation of cruisecontrol. We are using the Java version of cruisecontrol and to do this I wrote an .xsl transformation which also uses the  element.

The transformation works as follows :

A user can define in the configuration file entries such as these :

```
<include.projects file="Projects\3DDependencies\3DDependencies_cc_config.xml">
    <property name="BuildType" value="dll"/>
    <property name="BuildType" value="cfg"/>
    <property name="BuildType" value="msi"/>
</include.projects>
```

Then the xslt reads the file defined in the file attribute and creates a  element with the build elements defined by the user e.g. ${project.name}.dll, ${project.name}.cfg etc.

It then copies - if needed any other elements such as publishers etc. In this way one can have a "base" configuration and override this configuration on a per project basis.

It also allows the user to add/remove as many builds as he wants.